# new object is default transparent on blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, blenderkit

I have deleted blender 2.92 and installed an older version (2.82). And I open a new project. The default cube on Blender is transparent. and on material preview, the cube is black. on render preview, it is working as expected. I do not know why on the solid mode it is transparent and on material view it is black?? The images are attached [image] please help me. I am a beginner and have started it recently. thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a known issue with AMD GPU's. Try enabling "High Quality Normals" under _Render Properties > Performance_.

Comment: Yes, this is! but I am running 2.82 and there is "High quality normals" option. I could not find it:(

Comment: I finally found a solution. I have downgraded my driver to  Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.1. and now it is working. Thank you